# index.php to which route redirects?

Tags: php, symfony

I am studying the symfony-demo project and I am faced with a doubt: This project is configured so that the index redirects to the route / is imagined to be taken from the locale. The fact is that I want to change the route to which the index redirects when it is set: www.mywebsite.com redirects to the route I want, I do not know how to achieve this, here I leave my index.php:

```
<?php

use App\Kernel;
use Symfony\Component\Debug\Debug;
use Symfony\Component\Dotenv\Dotenv;
use Symfony\Component\HttpFoundation\Request;

require __DIR__.'/../vendor/autoload.php';

// The check is to ensure we don't use .env in production
if (!isset($_SERVER['APP_ENV'])) {
    if (!class_exists(Dotenv::class)) {
         throw new \RuntimeException('APP_ENV environment variable is not defined. You need to define environment variables for configuration or add   "symfony/dotenv" as a Composer dependency to load variables from a .env   file.');
    }
(new Dotenv())->load(__DIR__.'/../.env');
}

$env = $_SERVER['APP_ENV'] ?? 'dev';
$debug = (bool) ($_SERVER['APP_DEBUG'] ?? ('prod' !== $env));

if ($debug) {
    umask(0000);

    Debug::enable();
}

if ($trustedProxies = $_SERVER['TRUSTED_PROXIES'] ?? false) {
    Request::setTrustedProxies(explode(',', $trustedProxies), Request::HEADER_X_FORWARDED_ALL ^ Request::HEADER_X_FORWARDED_HOST);
}

if ($trustedHosts = $_SERVER['TRUSTED_HOSTS'] ?? false) {
    Request::setTrustedHosts(explode(',', $trustedHosts));
}

$kernel = new Kernel($env, $debug);
$request = Request::createFromGlobals();
$response = $kernel->handle($request);
$response->send();
$kernel->terminate($request, $response);
```

I would also like to know how the demo redirects to /es as I searched and did not find.

Comment: I'm having trouble understanding you. Are you asking how everything redirects to `index.php` regardless of the URL? Or do you need an explanation how Routers and Controllers work in Symfony?

Comment: I know how to redirect to the index.php and also how the routes and controllers in symfony work, what I do not know is how the index.php redirects to other routes? Sorry my english is not so good.

Comment: What do you mean redirects to other routes?

Comment: As i said the symfony-demo project redirects to /es or /en depending the locale lang, but how? where is that configured? When redirecting to a route I have to put it in the URL for example: www.mywebsite.com/my_route. My problem: how can I get it to redirect to /my_route by setting only www.mywebsite.com.

Comment: Index.php is an application, so apache is routing all request to index.php and index.php is a Symfony Application, checking if request valid, sending to matched controller. when you type /es its routing to spanish, you can configure it from config files and routes files. "_locales" section. but I think you can solve your problem .htaccess not with index.php

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Don't touch the public/index.php file ...
Have a Controller which match with the "/" route's is one option where you can redirect!!!

```
class IndexController extends AbstractController
{
    /**
     * @Route("/", name="index")
     */
    public function index()
    {
         return $this->redirectToRoute('the_route_you_want');
    }
}
```